# Converting string to float using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a csv file in which the column has '$' and ',' in it. So, I am unable to replace them[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaGSN.jpg)

Please let me know if any solution available.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `dfnew['StartingMedianSalary'] = dfnew['StartingMedianSalary'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)`. Dont think you can use `and` inside a `replace`

Answer (score 0):

You're using str.replace incorrectly. Instead you should write:

`dfnew['StartingMedianSalary'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '').astype(float)`